# Issue while using AWAIT with GraphserviceClient in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, async-await, microsoft-graph-api, graphserviceclient

I am implementing Office 365 modern authentication using MSGraph in old application.
When I try to access emails using graphserviceclient object asynchronously in console VB.net application it stops execution without giving error.

Same code works fine in C#.

```
Dim messages = Await graphclientObj.Users("emailid").Messages.Request().GetAsync()
```

It stops the application.
Please suggest

Comment: what you mean stops the application? does it hang, does it crash? if crash, is there a stacktrace ?

Comment: Could you maybe edit in the C# code that works?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing.